# How to change the keyboard layout at the Windows XP login screen

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, language, layout

I have a Dell computer with Windows XP Home Edition on it. Yesterday I was fooling around with trying to make my computer read Japanese characters. So buy accident I changed the keyboard layout to Japanese. After a reboot I tried to enter my password but it wasn't accepted. The layout was still set to Japanese.

How can I change the keyboard layout at the Windows XP login screen?

Answer (score 2):

On the Windows XP login screen you can switch between installed keyboard layouts by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>

If that does not work try the following:

1. get a recovery boot CD which allows you to edit the registry (for example [BartPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BartPE))
2. boot off the recovery CD
3. start the registry editor
4. navigate to **[HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload]**
5. edit the **1** key to: **00020409** (US international)

Comment: Tried this and didnt work

Comment: @janai sorry to hear that. It works on my system. Did you remove the original keyboard layout? **Alt+Shift** only switches between installed layouts!

Comment: @janai I just added a second solution. It is a bit more complicated but I hope this one works for you.

Answer (score 0):

n the Windows XP login screen you can switch between installed keyboard layouts by pressing

alt+ctrl+shift working for me

Comment: This solution was already posted by another user several months ago. OP said it didn't work.